# Spring boot 2.7.3 with Spring boot Elastic search 2.5.7

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We recently upgraded Spring boot to 2.7.3. We have elastic search in one of our modules and hence worked on the necessary code changes for the same too.
Worked fine on local but we got an error while building in QA with following error

```
Invalid or missing build flavor [oss];
```

We realized that with AWS elasticsearch/opensearch (version 7.9.3), this caused an issue as there is a recent change in RestHighLevelClient to have an addition validation which only allows **default** as build flavor for elastic-search.

So decided to downgrade spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch to just 2.5.7

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2021

This led me to go through adding explicit transitive dependency for many artifacts

```
 <dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.12.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>7.12.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.plugin/transport-netty4-client -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.12.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.12.1</version>
  </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

But still when I start up my spring application, it is giving me error because some part of spring-auto-configure is which is of version 2.7.3 could not find necessary class because I have downgraded transitive dependency

So wanted to check if someone else has been in same soup as I am

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: We disabled the configuration with was using it which is. Then copied ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration of spring boot 2.5.7 in 
 class path @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.class)